# Finding the largest of 6 doubles in an array and storing as double

Tags: c++, arrays

I've got a struct, lets call it competitor. In this, there is an array of type Double holding the 6 heights of the competitor's jumps. There is also a double called "bestJump" which will then hold the highest jump, but this must be calculated.

The 6 jumps will be printed to a .txt file as a report, along with the best jump, and this information will also be displayed in the console.

```
void bestJump(competitor comp)
{
    comp.bestJump = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (comp.jump[i] > comp.bestJump)
        {
            comp.bestJump = comp.jump[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not return an error, but also does not return the largest double from the array. Instead, it returns
    -92559631349317830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00

Where have I gone wrong or what have I not done?

Comment: How are you observing the `comp.bestJump` value? Did you perhaps intend to make the function take its argument by reference (because right now it's working with a copy of the original object)? Can you post your **complete** code?

Comment: After fixing the reference passing,  this is a one line function: `comp.bestJump = *std::max_element(comp.jump, comp.jump + 6);`

Answer (score 3):

Another answer with a bit of tidying up:

```
void bestJump(competitor &comp)
{
    comp.bestJump = comp.jump[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        if (comp.jump[i] > comp.bestJump)
            comp.bestJump = comp.jump[i];
    }
}
```

This method accepts a reference as the function argument, as recommended by Cornstalks. Therefore .bestJump gets modified in the original object.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you want to pass the address of comp in and then do:

```
void bestJump(competitor * comp)
{
    comp->bestJump = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (comp->jump[i] > comp->bestJump)
        {
            comp.bestJump = comp.jump[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable to pass objects as reference.

What you did was to pass a copy of the object itself (pass by value to be precise) Hence, even if the correct value was assigned by `comp.bestJump = comp.jump[i]` upon returning from the function, the object is reset to state when the function was called.

You may even try defining the function `bestJump` as friend of the `competitor` class.